# Prove $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{2k}=4^n$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I once had to show that $\cos(x)\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$ using the Cauchy product and relied on $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{2k}=4^n.$$ However I never came up with a proof why this is true - is there any **short** proof why this holds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$2^{2n+1}
=(1+1)^{2n+1}
=\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} \binom{2n+1}{k}
$.

$0
=(1-1)^{2n+1}
=\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} (-1)^k\binom{2n+1}{k}
$.

Adding these,
$2^{2n+1}
=\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} \binom{2n+1}{k}(1+(-1)^k)
=2\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k}
$
so
$2^{2n}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k}
$.

Comment: Fastest fingers wins!

Comment: This proof definitely is as short as requested but easy to grasp nonetheless!